# using overided CSS style for popovers from a custom.css file in a ASP.NET MVC Helper TextBoxFor input box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I'm following this excellent tutorial about over riding the default popover styles using a custom CSS file.
http://benkaminski.com/2014/08/30/how-to-customize-bootstrap-3-popovers-individually-using-only-css/

I want to use popovers on fields from my data model using ASP.NET MVC 4 bootstrap3 and Razor views in my view model to display messages on focus to tell the user if a field is mandatory to fill out on a long web registration form.
This way they don't need to re-fill out the form if they miss a field that needs to be populated at the end of the registration form. I want to accomplish this by using Html helper methods Html.TextBoxFor on each field using code like this.

```
      Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2, htmlAttributes: new
           {   data_container = "body",
               data_toggle = "popover",
               data_trigger = "focus",
               data_role = "tooltip",
               data_class = "arrrow",
               data_placement = "right",
               data_content = "Address2 is not mandatory field to complete"

           })
```

On the link above I want to incorporate the class popover3 and have those stlyes displayed on thee popover in the view when user mouses or tabs over field. The Html to do this from the tutorial above is this.

```
<div class="text-center example-class3" data-container="body" data-template='<div class="popover3" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>' data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Address2 is not a mandatory field"></div>
```

Now I want to take the attributes of the overridden CSS from above class in the Html Popover3 and put it in the above helper method so it shows the enhanced popover in the view. How do I get the class=popover3 attributes into the Html TextBoxFor helper method? Here is the CSS custom class I'm using

```
.slick-header *, *:before, *.after {
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
    */


[class^="slickgrid_"],
[class^="slickgrid_"] div {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}

.slick-header-columns-dla {
    background: #0000BD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font: 10pt Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}

.slick-header-columns-nondla {
    background: #00B96A;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font: 10pt Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}

.slick-cell {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: transparent #D4D4D4 #D4D4D4 transparent;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
    font: 11pt Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    padding: 1px 1px 0px 2px;
}

.slick-header-columns {
    background-color: #0063B0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font: 10pt Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}



.selected-header {
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    color: #217346;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slick-column-name {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

input.editor-text {
    background: none;
    border: 0 none;
    font: 11pt Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Cell Border, custom*/

.slick-cell.active {
    border-color: #0063B0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}

.slick-cell.invalid {
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-name: slickgrid-invalid-hilite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slickgrid-invalid-hilite;
    border-color: red;
}

@-moz-keyframes slickgrid-invalid-hilite {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 6px red; }

    to { box-shadow: none; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slickgrid-invalid-hilite {
    from { box-shadow: 0 0 6px red; }

    to { box-shadow: none; }
}





.example-class3 {
background-color: #bfd8ea;
height: 77px;
width: 77px;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
margin-top: 160px;
}


.btn-green {
    background-color: #00B96A;
    border-color: #357ebd;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-green-lg {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #00B96A;
    border-color: #357ebd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px; /*change this to your desired size*/
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 18px 28px;
}
/* ========== BEGIN POPOVER 3 ========== */
.popover3 {
position: fixed !important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1060;
display: none;
width: 250px !important;
padding: 1px;
text-align: left;
white-space: normal;
background-color: #bfd8ea !important;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-radius: 0px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.popover3.right {
margin-right: -10px;
}
.popover3 > .arrow,
.popover3 > .arrow:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
}
.popover3 > .arrow {
border-width: 11px;
}
.popover3 > .arrow:after {
content: "";
border-width: 10px;
}
.popover3.left > .arrow {
top: 50%;
right: -11px;
margin-top: -11px;
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-color: #999;
border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
.popover3.left > .arrow:after {
right: 1px;
bottom: -10px;
content: " ";
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-color: #bfd8ea !important;
}
/* ========== END POPOVER 3 ========== */
```

Comment: So what is not working ? What exactly is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry Shyju I was editing the code. I just saw this now. I want to make the popover3 CSS class display the newly edited popover style from within the Html.TextBoxFor . It is working right now for the default popovers but I want the popovers styled like .example-class3  using the .popover3 styles from the above Custom.CSS code.

Comment: so then change the divs using example-class3 to use popover3?